# How can I use a different id field for one of my CakePHP model associations?

Tags: php, cakephp, associations

I have an one to many association in which a Thing can have many Statuses defined as below:

Status Model:

```
class Status extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Status';

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Thing' => array(
            'className' => 'Thing',
            'foreignKey' => 'thing_id',
    );
}
```

Thing Model:

```
class Thing extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Thing';    

    var $belongsTo = array(
        // other associations
    );

    var $hasMany = array(
        'Status' => array(
            'className' => 'Status',
            'foreignKey' => 'thing_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'order' => 'datetime DESC',
            'limit' => '10',
        ),
        // other associations
    );
}
```

This works OK, but I would like Thing to use a different id to connect to Status. E.g. Thing would use 'id' for all of it's other associations but use 'thing_status_id' for it's Status association.

How can I best do this?

Comment: I think you're entering a world of pain doing this, you'll probably have to supply hand coded finder queries instead of being able to rely on Cakes automatic. Why do you want to obfuscate your own database this way?

Comment: The status table I don't have much control over as it gets it data from another source (which uses its own Thing id's).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end I could only get it to work by using a finderQuery with a SQL subquery.

Here is my Model:

```
class Thing extends AppModel
{
    // ...

    var $hasMany = array(
        'Status' => array(
            'className' => 'Status',
            'foreignKey' => 'thing_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'limit' => 10,
            'finderQuery' => '
                SELECT Status.* 
                FROM statuses AS Status 
                WHERE Status.thing_id = (
                    SELECT Thing.status_thing_id 
                    FROM things AS Thing 
                    WHERE Thing.id = {$__cakeID__$}
                )
                ORDER BY Status.datetime DESC
                LIMIT 0, 10',
        ),
    ),

    // ...
}
```

The really weird thing is if I remove the 'limit' => 10 line the query no longer works properly, even though that line doesn't do anything (I still need the LIMIT 0,10 in my SQL).

Answer (score 7):

`'foreignKey' => false` and `'conditions' => 'Thing.status_id = Status.thing_id'` for association options can figure out what you asking.
But I agree that using translation table for habtm relation.

Comment: That's another solution I was looking for, but couldn't remember. +1 :)

Comment: I did try this solution before posting but it does not work for me. I get a "Unknown column 'Thing.status_thing_id' in 'where clause'" error. Seems it doesn't translate Thing.status_thing_id into a number.

Answer (score 2):

> The status table I don't have much control over as it gets it data from another source (which uses its own Thing id's).

Maybe it's better to introduce a "translation table" and make a HABTM relationship out of it. It also counteracts the "pollution" of your Thing table with data that's not strictly necessary.

```
things
   id
   ...

   HABTM Status
       with => ThingAltId

thing_alt_ids
   id
   thing_id
   status_thing_id
   ...possibly other ids used to identify Thing in 3rd party systems...

statuses
   id
   thing_id

   HABTM Thing
       with => ThingAltId
```

Comment: Thanks deceze, this approach makes a lot of sense to me. I'm going to try and implement now.

Comment: Actually, I was just going to comment that this is probably not quite working as is, but hopefully it inspires the right solution. Please post actual code once you find it. :)

Comment: I couldn't get the HABTM relationship working using the correct id fields. In the end used finderQuery with a SQL subquery to map the id's which works at least.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `foreignkey` whatever you want.So I think you can just change `'foreignKey' => 'thing_id',` to `'foreignKey' => 'thing_status_id',` and alter the column `thing_id` in the table of `Statuses`.

Comment: Not that easy unfortunately. Even if you rename the foreign key to `thing_status_id` in the `Status` model, it will still refer to `Thing.id` in the `Thing` model. AFAIU, that's what the OP wants to change, `Status.thing_id` should refer to `Thing.thing_status_id`.

Comment: Yeah you're right deceze, what I would really like is a 'primaryKey' field to define on a per association basis.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding.Since ForeignKey should be the Primarykey of some model,so I think maybe this cannot be done by the cake's options.